# why Variable has incomplete type 'struct file_operations' though importing fs.h?

Tags: c, linux, fs, chardev

I try to import the struct of  file_operations
and get this error:

```
Variable has incomplete type 'struct file_operations'
```

my imports are

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>   /* We're doing kernel work */
#include <linux/module.h>   /* Specifically, a module */
#include <linux/fs.h>       /* for register_chrdev */
#include "sys/types.h"
```

and the error is here at fops:

```
 struct file_operations Fops =
        {
                .owner    = THIS_MODULE, // Required for correct count of module usage. This prevents the module from being removed while used.
                .read           = device_read,
                .write          = device_write,
                .open           = device_open,
                .release        = NULL
        };
```

minimal code:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>   /* We're doing kernel work */
#include <linux/module.h>   /* Specifically, a module */
#include <linux/fs.h>       /* for register_chrdev */
#include "sys/types.h"

 struct file_operations Fops =
        {
                .owner    = THIS_MODULE, // Required for correct count of module usage. This prevents the module from being removed while used.
                .read           = device_read,
                .write          = device_write,
                .open           = device_open,
                .release        = NULL
        };
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. I think puttig both code parts in one .c might do the trick, but you need to make that clear.

Comment: @Yunnosch added

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula I doubt it. The answer there is basically "You need to include the header that has that declaration.". Which OP here explicity explained that they considered and acted on. At least some details are needed why OPs header, though promising, does NOT serve that purpose.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula nope

Comment: There is an important difference between "full code" and [mre]. Please read the linked info and apply the concept.

Comment: I added as requested

Comment: Is each of the includes in your minimal code really needed? I still think you did not get the concept. Also, you now have what looks like the same code twice, once in pieces, once as one block.

Comment: I believe it now is

Comment: What compiler are you using?  It might not support "dot initialization" of structs. It's a C99 feature afaik.. I had a very similar issue once on an ARM MCU.

Answer (score 2):

If you compare your code to the definition of `file_operations()` in https://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/linux/kernel/3.7/structfile__operations.html you have not initialized many fields, possibly this is why the incomplete error is thrown.

> Some operations are not implemented by a driver. For example, a driver
> that handles a video card won't need to read from a directory
> structure. The corresponding entries in the file_operations structure
> should be set to NULL.

source : https://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/c577.htm

Normally your way is valid if you have the C99 extension for gcc